# TFS custom plugin ignored by Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I wrote a plugin with some field validation. It's works for every user, besides only one. It just ignored when he works. But if he works with RDP -connection to server where TFS installed (user is the same) it works. What issue is it can be?

Answer (score 0):

If he can works in a remote client. So, there is none error with his account.

Please use another account which can works well on his local computer to narrow down this issue.

If it still doesn't work, suggest you to delete TFS cache by going into default `C:\ {User Profile Folder}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache` and VS cache in `appdata` folder. Or reinstall VS.